# In-memory data store in the Ballerina: implementation, limitations, and scaling

Tags: in-memory-database, persist, ballerina-swan-lake

I recently came across the in-memory datastore support of `bal persist` feature. Regarding this, could you provide the following details?

- What is the underlying implementation of this?
- How well does it scale?
- What are the limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store data in in-memory, we use Ballerina [tables](https://ballerina.io/spec/lang/master/#tables) underneath and use generated clients to access the tables. There is a Ballerina table created for each entity defined in the model. in-memory data store supports all Ballerina types, but this is a volatile memory.